# Why do Android phone manufacturers describe RAM in powers of 1,000 but not 1,024 (as PCs do)?

Tags: ram, history

For PC RAMs, when a manufacturer say they produce a 4GB memory bank, they are producing a memory bank with 4,294,967,296 bytes (4 **GiB**). The same applies to CPU cache, i.e. a CPU with 2MB L3 cache means 2,097,152 bytes (2 **MiB**) of L3 cache.

For hard drives, flash drives (USB drives, SSDs, eMMCs and UFSs) and optical discs (CDs, DVDs and BDs), manufacturers use powers of 10<sup>3</sup> for B, KB, MB and GB, so a 4GB USB drive has *roughly* 4,000,000,000 bytes.

According to my observation, Android phone manufaturers use the latter kind of units when advertising RAM. That does not sound reasonable to me because PCs' RAMs aren't advertised that way.

**Edit**: I am an experienced Android user. I have investigated the kernel and made sure that other components' sharing RAM does *not* affect my observation.

Comment: You're almost certainly seeing a lower value for RAM because of things like the Radio and GPU stealing areas of RAM from the CPU.

Comment: See [Does Android hide some amount of RAM from the User?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20256/does-android-hide-some-amount-of-ram-from-the-user) and [Why does it seem like I have less RAM than advertised?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59933/why-does-it-seem-like-i-have-less-ram-than-advertised?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does it seem like I have less RAM than advertised?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59933/why-does-it-seem-like-i-have-less-ram-than-advertised)

Comment: @Mokubai **I've seen that post. Other components sharing system RAM is not the answer I'm looking for, and it does not affect answers to my question.**

Comment: @Mokubai I wouldn't have written the title as "unit switching issue" if I was looking for a general RAM shortage answer. I'm asking specifically of issue with units.

Comment: Where exactly are you "observing" that Android is using a different notation from PCs?

Comment: @Mokubai `cat /proc/meminfo` Line 1: `MemTotal: 7909028 kB`. Small k means roughly 7,909,028,000 bytes, which is far from 8 GiB = 8,589,934,592 bytes.

Comment: The Linux kernel will not necessarily see memory allocated to the graphics chip or radio. It will be cordoned off for their dedicated use before Linux sees it. I'm not disputing the small-k and Linux could be showing it using non-binary prefixes but that would actually make it appear that you had *more* memory available as memory chips use the old notation to denote size which would make a system showing decimal notation for size show a larger figure.

Comment: To clarify, some devices do not **share** system RAM, they actively block the rest of the system from accessing that area of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl:dr**:  Android memory is more in line with hard disk memory and uses the SI or decimal standards unlike PC memory. Standards support this

---

Basing my answer on [What is the advantage to using a factor of 1024 instead of 1000 for disk size units? - Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218194/what-is-the-advantage-to-using-a-factor-of-1024-instead-of-1000-for-disk-size-un) and bringing out only the key aspects. Details can be referred in that question

- In the case of PC's, quoting  from the [accepted answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/218236) **binary** addressing was adopted

> It is kind of convenience and optimization for getting the most usable, addressable space between the **two considerations of addressing and physical platter size**

- For Disk drives **SI** units were adopted. From [Bobson's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/218238)

> The disk drive industry followed a **different** pattern. Industry practice, more thoroughly documented at [Timeline of binary prefixes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_binary_prefixes)
>    and continuing today, is to specify hard drives using SI prefixes and symbols in their SI or "decimal" interpretation. Unlike binary-addressed computer main memory, there is **nothing in a disk drive that influences it to have a total capacity easily expressed using a power of 1024**.

(Emphasis Supplied)

That explains in brief the reasons for binary and SI

---

**Evolution of Mobile Phones and Standards**

- The [earliest commercial model phone  DynaTAC 8000X](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone)appeared on the scene in  1983. [It couldn't do anything more than basic calls](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_phone) so RAM doesn't come into play
- By [1987](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_binary_prefixes) hard drives were marked in **SI** units as can be seen from the binary timeline linked
- **Feature Phones:** [IBM Simon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Simon) was the first feature phone in 1994, which had 1 MB of RAM and 1MB of storage expandable to 2 MB - you read that right :) So, when the feature phone cane out , SI standards were in vogue

So, *likely reasons* :

- SI standards were automatically applied to mobile memory as they were more viewed as storage elements rather than computational requirements
- Fact that memory was / is not based on platters (see accepted answer ) ,  adopting binary system made no sense . Instead of having separate nomenclature for storage and RAM, SI units were adopted for both. But in the case of PC's legacy continued, though one could argue that it is incorrect. Mac OS since 
  has since version 10.6 (Mountain Lion in 2011) shown hard drive size using [decimal prefixes and continues to do so](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)
- By [1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_binary_prefixes)

> IEC     introduces unambiguous prefixes for binary multiples (KiB, MiB, GiB etc.), reserving kB, MB, GB and so on for their decimal sense

- By [2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_binary_prefixes) Linux Kernel (used in Android) adopted IEC standards

Comment: I like the point which states perhaps " SI standards were automatically applied to mobile memory as they were more viewed as storage elements rather than computational requirements", it could explain the "theory of conspiracy by manufacturers sticking to SI probably it was an added advantage to marketing RAM

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia:

> The use of gigabyte may  be ambiguous. Hard disk capacities as
>   described and marketed by drive manufacturers use the standard metric
>   definition of the gigabyte. Therefore, one gigabyte is 1 000 000 000
>   bytes(GB).

This is true even for phone manufacturers, in fact just as [rjknight](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7540344) pointed out, The RAM marketing strategy is similar to the "hard drive maker conspiracy" story is driven by the fact that manufacturers have no real incentive to switch to binary prefixes, because that would make their drives (RAM in this case) look "smaller".

---

AFAICT, using the **mebibyte (MiB)**, **gibibyte (GiB)** and so on, is a more accurate way of presenting the volume of data stored in these quantities.

**In depth**

> The gibibyte or binary gigabyte is a multiple of the unit byte for
>   digital information . The binary prefix gibi means 2^30 , therefore
>   one gibibyte is equal to 1 073 741 824 bytes = 1024 mebibytes .

These other binary prefixes (kibi, mebi, tebi, etc.) were introduced in an attempt to reduce such confusion, but these prefixes have yet to see widespread adoption.

In PC 2GB of ram refers to gibibytes, not gigabytes. RAM comes in allocation in powers of 2 due to architecture. Memory addressing is done in binary form, this implies it is going to be a power of two.

So, since writing memory addresses in binary always results in a binary number, RAM developers have (almost) always stuck to creating RAM in units of powers of 2, combining individual chips which are (almost) always combining to powers of 2.

Here is another [explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/jcsqg/why_does_ram_come_in_specific_sizes_256_512_1024/):

> RAM is addressable by an index called an address . The most efficient
>   way to construct this address is as a binary number which corresponds
>   to the physical area on the chip where the byte or word of memory is
>   accessed from. As a matter of efficiency its expensive to check this
>   address for validity (does the address really correspond to a real
>   address?) for every access. The only way to restrict the address 
>   range
>   without having to check the value is to allow for every possible
>   combination of bits, but set the exact number of valid bits that are
>   supported for the RAM chip. But that means your range has to be a
>   power of 2.

---

**Mobile phones**

> RAM that is used in smartphones is technically DRAM, with the D
>   standing for dynamic. The structure of DRAM is such that each
>   capacitor on the RAM board stores a bit, and the capacitors leak
>   charge and require constant “refreshing”; thus the “dynamic” nature of
>   the RAM. It also means that the contents of the DRAM module can be
>   changed quickly and easily to store different files.

And as expected, the exact number of bytes in a DRAM module is always an integral power of two.

**Conclusion**

This is is more like a business idea, that takes advantage of confusion regarding the common usage of "gigabyte" instead of "gibibytes" much like ISPs advertise 8Mbps (= 1MBps) as 8MBps, so it needs awareness from end users or customers.

It seems most manufacturers hide under metric system or SI units to "advertise" to  the unsuspecting consumers, although in real terms the say what they don't mean.

Acknowledgements

- [Gigabyte](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte)
- [Why is 1 GB equal to 10^9 bytes instead of 2^30?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7540344)
- [Why does RAM come in specific sizes (256, 512, 1024, 2048, etc)](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/jcsqg/why_does_ram_come_in_specific_sizes_256_512_1024/)
- [About Random Access Memory (RAM)](https://www.neowin.net/news/guide-to-smartphone-hardware-37-memory-and-storage)

Comment: You said the RAMs in mobile phones are DRAMs, but that makes no difference because PC RAMs are also DRAMs. Also your PC won't fail if you install banks with different capacities, making the total RAM not a integral power of 2.